# how to remember rejected permissions for Facebook?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook

In my app, I use Facebook connect, to sign in directly with users's Facebook account,
every thing is fine, but, as I am asking for publish_stream permision; some users reject this permission, the question is how can I remember which permissions were rejected ?

I need to know this info, otherwise, user will keep rejecting publish_stream permision each time he sign in with his Facebook account!

I need to know so that I don't ask him again .. any idea ?

Comment: You can make a call to me/permissions to see what permissions the user has provided, and if publish_stream doesn't show up..then you know the user has rejected that perm.

Comment: possible duplicate of [check for extended permissions with new facebook javascript sdk](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/3388367/check-for-extended-permissions-with-new-facebook-javascript-sdk)

Comment: me/prrmissions read from a coockie ? as i will need the info before signing in ..